# connect to HiveMetaStore from HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, hivecontext

I'm doing some tests on tables I created via HiveContext.sql(). Are there anyways I can connect to underlying HiveMetaStore using org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient?

I tried to init HiveMetaStoreClient(hiveContext.hiveconf()) but I can't see tables from the HiveMetaStoreClient.

Comment: which version of the spark you are using ?

Comment: which version of the spark you are using ? 1.6.1

Comment: Have you configured spark correctly ...http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html